# Графический интерфейс пользователя в linux(gnome).

Tags: gnome, c++, ubuntu

Я обладаю базовыми знаниями в C++
хочу научится создавать графический интерфейс под ubuntu, которая использует gnome.
подскажите какое нить руководство.

Answer (score 3):

Графическая библиотека, на которой строятся GNOME и xfce, называется GTK+. Заточена на программирование в С. Несмотря на большую распространенность, хороших современных  пособий практически нет:(

Пожалуй, из того, что мне известно, лучшая книга Andrew Krause. Foundations of GTK+ Development. По-русски в 2000 г. была издана книга Грифитса, но она безнадежно устарела. В инете есть  статьи и  очерки по отдельным областям GTK.

Еще можно порекомендовать библиотеку Qt. Она построена на С++. Книг по ней побольше, есть хорошие книги на русском, переводные и оригинальные. На форуме уже они неоднократно упоминались, поищите.

Comment: Есть ещё Vala, заточенный под Glib+GTK

Answer (score 0):

Начинайте отсюда: http://www.gtk.org/

Там и документация к API и туториалы и статьи и полезные ссылки.